# Using $this in method called with call_user_func_array

Tags: php, arrays, oop

I have a method, which simplified looks like this:

```
class Foo {

   public function bar($id) {
      // do stuff using $this, error occurs here
   }

}
```

Calling it like this works great:

```
$foo = new Foo();
$foo->bar(1);
```

However, if I call it using [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array), like this:

```
call_user_func_array(array("Foo", "bar"), array('id' => 1));
```

Which *should* be equal, I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in

*(`$this` is undefined)*

Why is this? Is there something I am missing? How should I do this so I still can use `$this` in the called method?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`array("Foo", "bar")` is equal to `Foo::bar()`, i.e. a static method - this makes sense since `$foo` is nowhere used and thus PHP *cannot* know which instance to use.

What you want is `array($foo, "bar")` to call the *instance* method.

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php for a list of the various callables.

---

You also need to pass the arguments as an indexed array instead of an associative array, i.e. `array(1)` instead of `array('id' => 1)`

Comment: Just for the record there is a second mistake in his code, `array('id' => 1)` should rather be `array(1)` judging by his definition of `bar`

Comment: Hah! Should've seen that coming, didn't think it was that simple. Thanks a ton! Regarding your edit: that's a typo, wrote that code in the SO-ask window :-). Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same using:

```
(new $className())->$methodName(...$arrayWithParams)
```